# jekyll assign concat in a loop?

Tags: jekyll, concatenation

I would like to organize a page based on the number of pages that pass a filter.

I have tried to append truthy pages to a collection but it doesn't work.

```
{% assign homepage_posts = [] %}
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.homepage %}
    {% assign homepage_posts = homepage_posts | concat: [my_page] %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<h1>size{{homepage_posts.size}}</h1>
<h1>{{homepage_posts}}</h1>
```

This is not working. Does concat only work with strings?

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll will use Liquid 4 soon. But, for now, no `concat`.

In your case you can :

Create an empty array (bracket notation doesn't work in liquid) : `{% assign homepage_posts = "" | split:"/" %}`

`{{ homepage_posts | inspect }}` --> output : `[]`

And push elements in it :

```
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.homepage %}
    {% assign homepage_posts = homepage_posts | push: mypage %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ homepage_posts | inspect }}
```

Comment: I can't see it there https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v3.0.6/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb.

Comment: But in 4, yes : https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v4.0.0.rc1/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb

Comment: That is right, but try this with jekyll 3.4.0 (using liquid 3.0.6): `$ jekyll new n` `$ cd n` `$ echo '{% assign fruits = "apples, oranges, peaches, tomatoes" | split: ", " %}{% assign vegetables = "broccoli,
 carrots, lettuce, tomatoes" | split: ", " %}{% assign plants = fruits | concat: vegetables %}{{ plants | join: ", " }}' >> index.md` why it works?

Comment: For me, with Jekyll 3.4.0, result is `apples, oranges, peaches, tomatoes`. `concat` is nowhere around and this filter fails silently, like any other non existent filter.

Answer (score 0):

`concat` filter only works with arrays and will be available in Jekyll when it upgrades to Liquid 4.*:

> concat
>
> Concatenates (combines) an array with another array. The resulting
>   array contains all the elements of the original arrays. concat will
>   not remove duplicate entries from the concatenated array unless you
>   also use the uniq filter.

To filter pages containing a specific attribute (in this case `homepage: true`) you can use a `where` filter.

Having a page with front matter:

```
---
homepage: true
---
```

Then you can have the pages with the `homepage: true` attribute like:

```
{% assign homepages = site.pages | where:"homepage","true" %}
```